# PHPUnit Symfony v3.4 inheritance is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony4, symfony-3.4

After upgrading to Symfony v3.4. I keep getting following error on the PHPUnit test.

> Remaining deprecation notices (1)
>
> 1x: Bundle inheritance is deprecated as of 3.4 and will be removed in
>   4.0.
>       1x in GeoTest::testDistanceDuration from Tests\AppBundle\Util\Geo

Following is the test file

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Util\Geo;

use AppBundle\Util\Geo\GeoException;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class GeoTest extends WebTestCase {
    public function testDistanceDuration ()
    {
        $client = $this->createClient();

        $geo = $client->getContainer()->get('geo');

        $returnData = $geo->getDistanceDuration([51, -0.34], [51, -0.11]);

        $this->assertArrayHasKey('distance', $returnData);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('duration', $returnData);
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $returnData['distance']);
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $returnData['duration']);
    } 
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Edited, another simple test which does not pass and gives an error.

```
public function testShowPost()
{
    $client = static::createClient(); // < this is causing the error

    $this->assertEquals(200, 200);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm tired but [Functional Tests](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#functional-tests) are the same also in Symfony4 and the Deprecation refers to [Bundle Inheritance](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html). Maybe an error in the docs? Probably you override something somewhere related to this test using bundle inheritance?

Comment: @gp_sflover I have tried the functional test method too, it still gives me same error.

Comment: I haven't upgraded any project yet :-) (so also any tests), but what do you think to make a simple test on a fresh Symfony 4.1 install to then exclude (if it gives you the same error) that the issue is not due to a not updated docs? So strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly an **error** even if it appears with a red background. It is a notice, but your test is passing.

As per as [Symfony 3.4 Bundle Inheritance documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/inheritance.html):

> Bundle inheritance is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and will be removed in 4.0.

So Maybe in your own logic, you extend another bundle. You should check your AppBundle or whatever you have. Or you use a third-party bundle (installed with **Composer**) which does the same.

You have **2** solutions:

1. Fix the deprecation by updating your own logic or update the third-party bundle causing this deprecation. If this bundle does not have any update, you should consider stopping using it.
2. You should use the [PHPUnit Bridge](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/phpunit_bridge.html) to **silent this deprecation notice** if you don't want to fix it right now (at your own risks obviously). Especially by [Marking the Test as Legacy](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/phpunit_bridge.html#mark-tests-as-legacy)

**Edit:**

> but I found the error is caused by ` $client = static::createClient();

Check also if you have set the correct path for the kernel in your **phpunit.xml.dist**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" charset="utf-8" ?>
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    <!-- ... -->
</phpunit>
```

Comment: It is not passing the test. I have tried a very simple test, but I found the error is caused by ` $client = static::createClient();` code, which is part of all the test and Symfony test examples also. 

If the test was passing, then I could silent it, but it's not.

Comment: You did not show the report of your test, you showed only the report of the depreciation notice, how could we know to resolve your issue? Y

Comment: So the deprecation notice is not the concrete error. Please edit your post and  add the exact error report in order to propose a corresponding solution

Comment: Test report shows this error: `Error : Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser::parseFile()
`

Comment: Maybe your test is using a mock of your Yaml Parser. Is there any logic using the Yaml Parser when calling the Geo Service getDistanceDuration method? I suspect that the Yaml Parser is not instantiated from the container

Comment: updating phpunit to `5.7.27` makes it working condition with notice error

Answer (score 2):

**Seeing Is Believing**.

Let's assume that the deprecation message sounds like this:

> Bundle inheritance is deprecated as of 3.4 and will be removed in 4.0.

What does it mean? It might mean that you/someone have created a bundle (eg. MyBundle) that that overrides the `getParent()` function like this:

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
    * Returns the bundle parent name.
    *
    * @return string|null The Bundle parent name it overrides or null if no parent
    */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'Some3rdPartyBundleName';
    }
...
```

This is not supported anymore starting with Symfony 4.0. So simply by removing this implementation the deprecation warning should cease.

But [why have we used bundle inheritance](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-deprecated-bundle-inheritance) until Symfony 4, anyway?

> This inheritance mechanism was traditionally used to override some
>   templates, controllers and other elements of third-party bundles. In
>   Symfony 4.0 you'll need to use alternative solutions to override those
>   elements.